# Time complexity of obtaining the support set of an unsorted sequence?

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, sets, hashing

Consider a sequence $s$ of $n$ integers (let's ignore the specifics of their representation and just suppose we can read, write and compare them in O(1) time with arbitrary positions). What's known about the worst-case time complexity of producing a sequence of all distinct elements in $s$, in any order?

By randomized hashing, one can do this in expected $O(n)$ time. On the upper bound side, one may sort the elements, then produce the output in a single pass by only copying elements which differ from their predecessors to the output - for a total time of $O(n \log(n))$.

But can one do better than $O(n  \log(n) )$ deterministically?

Note: This is sort-of a "remove duplicates" problem, but since the order is not preserved I'm not sure it should be called that.

Comment: There is an $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound on element distinctness (finding out whether all elements are distinct) in the comparison model. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I don't think we can ignore the specifics of the representation and computational model because sorting is known to be somewhat delicate and dependent on that -- for instance, Wikipedia seems to suggest it is known how to sort in $O(n \log n / \log \log n)$ time in some computational models, and even in $O(n (\log \log n)^2)$ time.  So at least in some computational models that is a "yes one can do better" answer to your question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Comparisons model, eh? I think perhaps not, since the hashing strategy, while non-deterministic, is not in the comparisons model. But +1 on that comment.

Comment: When we have unbounded memory, $h(m)=m$ is a realizable hash function without conflict. The time-complexity is deterministic $O(n)$. (The space-complexity is $O(\max(a_i))$,  where $\max(a_i)$ is the maximum of given numbers. Every time a larger number is read, we double the working space .)

Comment: @Apass.Jack: The case of $max\{s\} - min\{s\} = O(n)$ is too narrow for me, and in the general case your suggestion doesn't seem to help.

Comment: If we can hash a number in O(1) time, can we suppose that it has O(1) bits?

Comment: @Bulat: No. Just pretend the computational model is such that allows these operations. Of course if the numbers had $O(1)$ bits then you could sort them in $O(n)$ time, i.e. use Apass.Jack's idea of identity hashing.

Comment: @einpoklum It seems you misunderstand me a bit. Suppose that the $\max$ is $n^{7}$, the time-complexity by identity hash is still $O(n)$. We are just using more space. Of course, if your numbers might be larger than $2^{32}$, then the method is of little practical value assuming the available memory to a process is less than that.

Comment: @Apass.Jack: Has is the time complexity $O(n)$ in that situation?

Comment: @einpoklum We allocate an array $arr$ of size, for simplicity, infinite with the default value 0 in $O(1)$-time (the default value 0 for all elements is part of the particular RAM model, which is actually reasonable). For $a_i$, if $arr[a_i]=1$, ignore. Otherwise, set $arr[a_i]=1$ and add $a_i$ to the set of distinct elements. Larger space-complexity is traded for less time-complexity.

Comment: No, it isn't. You need to initalize, and finally read, the entire array.

Comment: @einpoklum "The default value 0 for all elements is part of the particular RAM model" (that I defined). If you do not think that is a valid computation model at all, it is your choice. Note that for example all cells of a Turing machine are assumed to contain the blank symbol. That is (part of the reason) why I believe it is reasonable to include that in  my computation model.  By the way, we do not "finally read the entire array" since we will add an element $a_i$ to the set of distinct elements only when $arr[a_i]$ is changed from 0 to 1. So at the end, we will just return that set.

Comment: Another to proceed is that we will allocate the array $arr$. Assume that we have a symbol such that for all $i$, $arr[i]$ is not that symbol. For each $a_i$, if $arr[a_i]$ is that symbol, ignore. Otherwise, set $arr[a_i]$ to be that symbol.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : I do expect many equal keys, but with equal values, so that's actually good for me.