# Find a non-minimal sequence of elements covering the support set

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sorting, arrays, hashing

Consider a sequence $s$ of $n$ integers (let's ignore the specifics of their representation and just suppose we can read, write and compare them in $O(1)$ time with arbitrary positions). Denote $\text{supp}(s) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{N} \;|\; x \in s \right\}$, the support set for $s$.

We are interested in obtaining a *supporting sequence* $s'$ of elements such that  $\text{supp}(s) = \text{supp}(s')$; in other words, we want a sequence of elements, in any order and possibly with repetitions, with appearances of all of elements appearing in $s$ (and no others).

The minimum such sequence is any ordering of the actual support set for $s$. But - we don't need the minimum itself. In fact, we are given a size bound $m$, and must produce an $s'$ with $|s'| \leq m$.

What algorithmic approach would you suggest for producing $s'$, which would have meaningfully better than just obtaining the exact support set - in terms of worst-case time complexity?

This question is related to [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88429/11796).

Notes:

- The algorithm is *not* limited to just comparisons (so hashing is on the table if you like).
- Obviously, the complexity cannot be any better than $\Theta(n)$, since you have to actually read all the input; and it can't be worse than $\Theta(n \log(n))$, with which complexity you can just obtain the exact support.
- Constant-factor improvements are significant, e.g. fewer reads of each element, even if the $O(\cdot)$ or $\Theta(\cdot)$ class might be same. I'm hoping for something that depends on $m$ or $m - |s'|$ obviously.

Comment: Better in what respect?  Are you trying to minimize worst-case running time?  What's your model of computation?  Do you require a deterministic algorithm?  Do you require an algorithm that uses only comparisons?  Do you need a streaming/online algorithm?  The running time of different algorithms might depend in a delicate way on these assumptions.  What counts as significant?  You're not going to be able to get more than a $O(\log n)$-factor speedup.

Comment: @D.W.: Sorry, I should have added more details before submitting the question. See edit.

Comment: I still wonder if hashing might be the best solution.  I see that in your previous question you rejected it because it is not deterministic, but given that you mention constant-factor improvements, I wonder whether hashing might actually be the best solution.  If you use 2-universal hashing, not only is the expected running time $\Theta(n)$, but we can also prove that there is a small constant $c$ such that there is only an exponentially small probability that the running time exceeds $c\cdot n$.  I don't think it makes engineering sense to worry about exponentially small probabilities; [..]

Comment: they are smaller than the probability that a cosmic ray hits your microprocessor and causes it to produce the wrong output or enter an infinite loop.  If we're willing to accept the risk of cosmic-ray-induced faults (which most people seem to be), then it seems like we also ought to be willing to accept the risk of an exponentially small chance of getting a poor random seed that causes our algorithm to take longer (or produce the wrong output).  [...]

Comment: From a theoretical perspective the difference between deterministic vs randomized algorithms is interesting, but if we adopt that theoretical perspective, constant factors are normally irrelevant.  So I'm struggling to find a context that would lead to the stated requirements and that also makes hashing unacceptable.

Comment: @D.W. : I didn't reject hashing, I only rejected _identity_ hashing, i.e. h(x) = x.

Comment: IIt seems like hashing is going to be pretty close optimal, then.  It reads each element once, and the running time is $\Theta(n)$ with a small constant factor.  All that remains is to optimize the constant factor, which might be tricky to do on paper, as it often depends on specific details like the architecture and cache/memory hierarchy of the system you are running on, and the typical size of these sets.

Comment: as @D.W. has mentioned, hashing seems to be the perfect algorithmic tool for your problem. Even an innocent linear hashing gives you good guarantees if $m\ge 2n$, and for a modest $O(k)$ per operation, you get a $k$-wise independent hash, a small $k=3,4$ would probably suffice for all practical purposes.

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki: Remember we're talking _worst-case_ complexity.

Comment: It doesn't handle worst-case complexity, but as mentioned in my previous comments, I'm having a hard time understanding why you care about worst-case complexity but also care about constant factors.  That makes it harder for me to know how to answer in a way that will be useful for what you're actually trying to achieve.